# Careers: History of favorited jobs isn't saved

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, bookmarks

Last week I saved a handful of jobs as "favorites". This week, they are all gone. Do favorited jobs only last during the lifetime of a single login? If so, I think this should be fixed. I'd like to be able to save some favorite jobs, and come back in a few days when I'm ready to apply.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, we had duplicate accounts and were able to resolve.